# How to perform fast float comparison in python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, loops, for-loop

I have the code that follows, where I compare float numbers of different vectors using for loops.

```
import numpy as np

a = 200

main_vector = np.random.random(a)
vector2 = np.random.random(a)
vector3 = np.random.random(a)
vector4 = np.random.randint(2, size=a)

list1 = [20, 35, 59, 80]

result_list = []

for i in list1:
    value2 = vector2[i]
    value3 = vector3[i]
    for j in range(1, a):
        if main_vector[i+j] >= value2:
            result_list.append(value2)
            break
        elif -main_vector[i+j] <= value3:
            result_list.append(value3)
            break
        elif vector4 == 1:
            result_list.append(main_vector[i+j])
            break
        else:
            # No action
            pass

print(result_list)
```

This is what the code does:

There are 4 vectors, which all are one dimensional numpy arrays of size a (which is a parameter stored in a variable in the code), and the idea is that a list of index positions are provided in list 'list1'.

The for loops have to check each number stored in the list named 'list1' and get the correspondig value of the 4 vectors in that index. Basically once a index is given you get 4 numbers.

Then a comparison is made between the value of main_vector and the other 3 values. If one of the conditions are met:

1. the value of the main_vector is greater than value2, or
2. the negative value of main_vector is greater than value 3, or
3. the value of vector4 is equal to 1,

then a number is given and stored in result_list, and if none of the conditions are met, then the next number of the main_vector is used to do the same comparison. The second loop is loped over until one of the conditions are met.

I want this code to be as fast as possible (using python), and I know that for loops are slow in python. Speed optimization is important in this case because the real vector and list dimensions are much larger than this example. Could you give some advice on how to improve the speed of this task?

Comment: Can you explain a bit what your code is meant to do?

Comment: I have edited the question with more details of what the code is meant to do. Thank you.

Comment: When I ran a test case of your code, `j` never stepped beyond 1.  On the first loop (for each list1 value), it picked either `value2` or `value3`.  With that `if ... break` logic, it will be hard to do any sort of `whole-array` processing.